# Flutter - How to change the color of an icon through boolean return?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, boolean

I have a function that checks what books are favorited in the Firestore, the book screen has an star icon, I use isFavorite function to check if is the opened book is favorited by the user or not, if so it returns true and the icon need to change it's color to yellow, if not it returns false and the color need to be black but the color is not changing.

The updateFavorite function works perfectly adding and removing the favorite book from Firestore when touching the icon.

```
InkWell(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.star,
            size: 30,
            color: isFavorite == true ? Colors.yellow
            : Colors.black,
          ),
          onTap: (){

            model.updateFavorite(model.getUserId(), document.documentID);
          },
        ),

==============

Future<bool> isFavorite() async{

            firebaseUser = await _auth.currentUser();

            DocumentSnapshot favoritesRef = await Firestore.instance.collection("users")
                .document(firebaseUser.uid).get();

            if(favoritesRef.data["favorites"].contains(document.documentID)){

              return true;
            }
            else {

              return false;
            }

          }

==============

      Future<bool> updateFavorite(Future<DocumentReference> uid, String bookId) async{

        firebaseUser = await _auth.currentUser();

        DocumentReference favoritesRef = Firestore.instance.collection("users")
            .document(firebaseUser.uid);

        return Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async{

          DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(favoritesRef);
          if(postSnapshot.exists){

            if(!postSnapshot.data["favorites"].contains(bookId)){
              await tx.update(favoritesRef, <String, dynamic>{
                "favorites": FieldValue.arrayUnion([bookId])

              });
              // Delete de bookId from Favorites
            } else {
              await tx.update(favoritesRef, <String, dynamic>{
                "favorites": FieldValue.arrayRemove([bookId])
              });

            }

          }

        }).then((result){
          print(firebaseUser.uid);
          print(bookId);
          return true;

        }).catchError((error){
          print("Error: $error");

          return false;
        });

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to do not use `isFavorite()` directly like that from `build`. The `build` method might get called constantly and it must have all the data it needs right away. (and the absence of the data must be dealt, for instance, with a loading animation)

Suggestion:

- make a property  `bool isFavorite` in your `State` class
- change your method `isFavorite()` to `_loadFavorite()`
- in `_loadFavorite()`, instead of returning the value, update the property `isFavorite` using `setState()`
- call `_loadFavorite()` in `initState()`

For the default value for `isFavorite`, you can either define it on `initState()`, you can set a default value like `false` OR keep it `null` and in your `build` method make the check, if it is `null`, then do not show any `Icon`, for instance (or even a loading icon).

If you want, you can aditionaly `listen` to the firestore reference to monitor if it gets changed, and if it does, you can update the state using `setState()` as well.